# Why doesn't JavaScript event.preventDefault() work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, preventdefault

I have a JavaScript function for an anchor tag that has preventDefault() in it. However, it seems like the function only delays the default rather than prevent it.

The purpose of this function is to use Ajax to navigate within the website so that the page does not refresh when I click on an internal link.

This appears to work as intended when the site has no CSS, but when I add the CSS, this is what happens when I click on an internal link to go from Page A to Page B:

1. Page B is properly loaded with all the HTML and CSS contents and the URL also changes via the Ajax method.
2. The page then refreshes to show only the HTML contents that was previously there but without the CSS styling.
3. The CSS styling finally appears.

I think this might be because preventDefault() only delayed the action of the "a" tag rather than completely disable it.

Is there any way to fix it?

Below is the code:

```js
const navigatePage = () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const a = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const b = event.target.pathname;
    a.open('GET', b, true);
    a.onprogress = () => document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = "Loading..";
    a.onload = () => {
        if (a.status == 200) {
            window.location.pathname = b;
            document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].textContent = new DOMParser().parseFromString(a.responseText, "text/html").head.childNodes[7].innerHTML;
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(a.responseText, "text/html").body.innerHTML;
        }
    }
    a.onerror = () => console.log('Error occured!');
    a.send();
}
```

```css
:root {
--main-color:red;
--secondary-color:pink;
--dark-color:#444;
--light-color:#fafafa;
--max-width:1000px;
}
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;text-decoration:none;color:var(--dark-color);}
body {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
background-color:var(--light-color);
color:var(--dark-color);
display: grid;
place-items: center;
font-size: 20px;
}
header{width:100%;display:flex;flex-wrap: wrap;align-items: center;justify-content:space-between;}
header img {height: 70px; width: 270px;}

.max-width{width: clamp(0px,var(--max-width),90%);}
```

```html
<div class="max-width">
        <header>
    <div><a href='/'><img src='logo-title.svg' alt="logo" /></a></div>
    <nav>
        <a href='/' onclick="navigatePage()">Home</a>
        <a href='about' onclick="navigatePage()">About</a>
        <a href='contact' onclick="navigatePage()">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</header>
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
        <p>There are 2 other pages with a different lorem ipsums and with h1 tags that say "About Page" and "Contact Page" respectively</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo rhoncus odio, nec interdum metus
            dignissim non.
            Nullam vel felis vel dolor finibus venenatis ac non quam. Donec sagittis sed libero vel aliquet. Ut finibus
            leo
            neque,
            quis consequat elit dictum at. Donec finibus tincidunt mauris ut ullamcorper. Sed bibendum viverra ante,
            eget
            pretium
            lectus porta sit amet. Mauris eget maximus nulla, at tempus odio. Nullam efficitur odio diam, et finibus
            sapien
            congue
            eu. Aenean luctus aliquet bibendum. Etiam erat erat, tincidunt feugiat felis at, mollis varius justo. Aenean
            dolor nisi,
            consequat vitae lacinia et, ullamcorper quis felis. Donec suscipit magna id urna interdum, ac pharetra arcu
            iaculis.
            Nulla et tristique neque, in auctor ipsum. Sed egestas, diam at ultricies blandit, enim nisl volutpat urna,
            eu
            dapibus
            elit massa ut nulla.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: 'event' is undefined, because you didn't pass the it into the navigatePage function. Also why are you using XMLHttpRequest? Try axios.

Comment: @mstephen19 While I agree on the implicit point about `XMLHTTPRequest`'s obsoleteness, why suggest to add yet another dependency when this task can be *easily* completed with the `fetch()` API in the browser...?

Comment: @esqew Ease of use, more features, but no qualms with fetch either. Over in MERN land we never really use fetch API, but I'm not against it by any means))

Comment: Assigning to `window.location.pathname` is what causes the navigation.

Comment: @niyojet344 does your page have a script src to the js file? From what I have managed to recreate I added <script src="script.js"></script> to the HTML file and in script.js I have put your javascript code and it works.

Comment: @AchoVasilev it's before the end of the body tag but it is not show in the question cause I only included what is meant to be changed.

Comment: @niyojet344 I think that window.location.pathName refreshes your page. Try with window.history.pushState('', 'New Page Title', 'someUrl');

Answer (score -1):

Try passing 'event' as an argument

```
const navigatePage = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // ... your code
}
```

Comment: going to have to have more changes than this. event is not passed in to the method when it is called.

Comment: @Rafhael I tried it but it did not make any changes.